# How can IntelliJ show type hints for automatically inferred local variables in Java 10?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, type-inference, java-10, type-hinting

IntelliJ shows type hints for local variables in Kotlin as shown here:

[image: Type hints in Kotlin]

This makes it easy to see the type of variables even if their types are inferred.
Java 10 introduces type inference for Java with the `var` keyword.
However, IntelliJ does not show any type hints by default:

[image]

After searching the internet for a bit, I was unable to find any information on how to enable type hints for local variables for Java.
Is this even possible currently?

I use IntelliJ Community Edition 2019.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: It's already supported, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-194935 .

Comment: Not quite the same feature -- what they have implemented is showing the hints when you fold the var declaration line.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Turn on option at:

**Preferences > Editor > Inlay Hints > Types > Java > Implicit types**.

[image]

---

You might also consider turn on all the options at:

**Preferences > Editor > Inlay Hints > Parameter names > Java**.

Answer (score 8):

In the latest version of IntelliJ (2020.3) these are called "Inlay Hints"

Preferences/Editor/Inlay Hints

Answer (score 1):

The closest feature in Java is `Replace 'var' with inferred type`:

```
Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Folding -> Replace 'var' with inferred type
```